# How to stop resetting the timer when the page refreshs using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my webpage I have a timer, it has to run all the time, but when the page refreshes the timer resets to 0. Guide me how to achieve this.

```js
var hours =0;
            var mins =0;
            var seconds =0;
            $('#start').click(function(){
                startTimer();
            });
            $('#stop').click(function(){
                clearTimeout(timex);
            });
            $('#reset').click(function(){
                hours =0;
                mins =0;
                seconds =0;
                $('#hours','#mins').html('00:');
                $('#seconds').html('00');
            });
            
            function startTimer(){
                timex = setTimeout(function(){
                    seconds++;
                    if(seconds >59){
                        seconds=0;mins++;
                        if(mins>59)
                        {
                            mins=0;
                            hours++;
                            if(hours <10) {
                                $("#hours").text('0'+hours+':');
                            }
                            else {
                            $("#hours").text(hours+':');
                            }
                        }                       
                        if(mins<10){                     
                            $("#mins").text('0'+mins+':');
                        }       
                        else {$("#mins").text(mins+':');
                        }
                    }    
                    if(seconds <10) {
                        $("#seconds").text('0'+seconds);
                        } else {
                        $("#seconds").text(seconds);
                        
                    }
                    startTimer();
                },1000);
            }
```

```css
#timer {
                font-size:150px;
                margin:0 auto;
                width:1000px;
            }
            #controls {
                margin:0 auto;
                width:600px;    
            }
            #controls button {
                font-size:24px;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<center>
            <div id="timer">
                <span id="hours">00:</span>
                <span id="mins">00:</span>
                <span id="seconds">00</span>  
            </div>
            <div id="controls">
                <button id="start">Start</button>
                <button id="stop">Stop</button>
                <button id="reset">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </center>
```

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 2):

For that, you should use a local-storage, or any technology to save data locally in the browser.

> localStorage.setItem('timer', your_time_var);

In there you have documentation how to use that: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You should store your timer before refresh.

Use `localStorage` and `onbeforeunload` event.

then whenever page loaded, set your timer with the previous timer value

Comment: actually, a cookie will do either.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution by using local storage

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            if(localStorage.getItem('timerValue')!= null)
            {
                var storageValue = localStorage.getItem('timerValue').trim();
                $('#timer').html(storageValue);
                const myArray = storageValue.split("</span>", 3);
                var hours =myArray[0].substring(0, myArray[0].length -1).slice(-2);
                var mins =myArray[1].substring(0, myArray[1].length -1).slice(-2);
                var seconds =myArray[2].slice(-2);
                startTimer();
            }
            else{
            $('#timer').html('<span id="hours">00:</span><span id="mins">00:</span><span id="seconds">00</span>');
                var storageValue = '<span id="hours">00:</span><span id="mins">00:</span><span id="seconds">00</span>';
                var hours =00;
                var mins =00;
                var seconds =00;
                startTimer();
            }
            
            $('#start').click(function(){
                startTimer();
            });
            $('#stop').click(function(){
                clearTimeout(timex);
            });
            $('#reset').click(function(){
                hours =0;
                mins =0;
                seconds =0;
                $('#hours').html('00:');
                $('#mins').html('00:');
                $('#seconds').html('00');
                localStorage.clear();
            });
            
            $('#timer').html(storageValue);
            
            function startTimer(){
                timex = setTimeout(function(){
                    seconds++;
                    if(seconds >59){
                        seconds=0;mins++;
                        if(mins>59)
                        {
                            mins=0;
                            hours++;
                            if(hours <10) {
                                $("#hours").text('0'+hours+':');
                            }
                            else {
                            $("#hours").text(hours+':');
                            }
                        }                       
                        if(mins<10){     
                            $("#mins").text('0'+mins+':');
                        }       
                        else {
                            $("#mins").text(mins+':');
                        }
                    }    
                    if(seconds <10) {
                            $("#seconds").text('0'+seconds);
                    } else {
                        $("#seconds").text(seconds);
                    }
                    var latestTimer = localStorage.setItem('timerValue', $('#timer').html());
                    startTimer();
                },1000);
            }
        });
```

```css
#timer {
                font-size:150px;
                margin:0 auto;
                width:1000px;
            }
            #controls {
                margin:0 auto;
                width:600px;    
            }
            #controls button {
                font-size:24px;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <div id="timer">
    <span id="hours">00:</span><span id="mins">00:</span><span id="seconds">00</span>  
  </div>
  <div id="controls">
    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <button id="stop">Stop</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
</center>
```